# How to infer the correct data type for a FHIR 'choice' property

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, hl7-fhir

I'm using the Fire.ly .NET SDK for parsing FHIR JSON into POCOs, to then send specific information to downstream processes.

As part of this, I need to read a FHIR **choice** property to a variable, which can basically be many different types. [The Fire.ly documentation has information on how to set one of these properties, but not read them](https://docs.fire.ly/projects/Firely-NET-SDK/model/choice-properties.html).

I've done something like this, but I'm not sure if this is going to work as the data I'm parsing doesn't have these fields set:

```cs
var deceasedDateTime = patient.Deceased as FhirDateTime;
var deceasedBool = patient.Deceased as FhirBoolean;
```

Does anyone know what the right way to parse these properties is?

Comment: HL7 is medical data usually in XML format according to the HL7 documentation.  Looks like your library can be set to JSON.  See : https://docs.fire.ly/projects/Firely-NET-SDK/client/setup.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks even better if you do pattern matching:

```cs
     if(patient.Deceased is FhirDateTime fdt)
     {
      // do things with fdt
     } 
     else if(patient.Deceased is FhirBoolean fb)
     {
       // etc.
     |
```

or

```cs
    var x = patient.Deceased switch
    {
        FhirDateTime dft =>  something,
        FhirBoolean => something else,
    
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question.

Once you've set your variable from the **choice** property, you can just type check it against the expected values.

For example:

```cs
var deceasedType = patient.Deceased?.GetType();

if (deceasedType != null && deceasedType == typeof(FhirDateTime))
{
  // foo
}
else if (deceasedType != null && deceasedType == typeof(FhirBoolean))
{
  // bar
}
```

Comment: (deleted)........